# Replace value in Json in Dataweave

Tags: json, mule, mule-studio, dataweave

The mule payload is in flowVars (infodata)

```
[
        {
        "status": "submitted",
        "identity": "",
        "papers": {
            "code1": "12csd3cbsdj",
            "code2": "skd02nd28dn",
            "date": "2016-06-22",
        "party": {
            "due_date": "2016-06-22",
            "personel": {
                "email": "tt@test.com",
                "value": {
                    "amount": "0.10",
                    "inflation": "HIGH"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Inside Dataweave, 
(1) how to remove the square brackets?
(2) how to replace the value of amount and inflation dynamically (from flowVars)?

Comment: You might want to show, what you already tried with dataweave code, to help people wnating to help with hints, as we're all coders here ...

Answer (score 0):

Question 2:You can directly use flowVars inside dataweave or if the values  are in url you can dynamically set values using `inboundProperties`. Refer: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation

I have used set variable where you can dynamically exact it.Test Url used in this flow:  http://localhost:8083/test?inflation=HIGH

```
   <flow name="testFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP">

    </http:listener>
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <set-variable variableName="dynamicValueAmount" value="#['2']" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
         %output application/json
         ---
        [
      {
    "status": "submitted",
     "identity": "",
      "papers": {     
  "party": {
    "due_date": "2016-06-22",
    "personel": {
      "email": "tt@test.com",
      "value": {
        "amount": flowVars.dynamicValueAmount,
        "inflation": inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.inflation

      }}}}}
]]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
      <set-payload value="#[ message.payload =org.mule.util.StringUtils.replace(message.payload,&quot;[&quot;,&quot;{&quot;);message.payload =org.mule.util.StringUtils.replace(message.payload,&quot;]&quot;,&quot;}&quot;)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
           <logger  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
```

Regarding Question one, i have externally used replace function in set Payload( Working fine - other way).  I believe it can be achieve in standard way by using Dataweave itself. Let wait for the answers.

Comment: Thanks! So inside my dataweave component I just want to reference the payload like below:

%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
 payload
}

Comment: You can refer the payload in which format you wanted to be either %output application/java or if you want your response in Json format %output application/json  ,if for xml %output application/xml. Check the  link for `ValidTypes` allowed in dataweave. https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/dataweave-reference-documentation

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers my question. To be clear, the payload needs to be dynamically changed for just the two fields (amount and inflation). I have updated the question to add the DW component.

Comment: I misunderstand your question earlier, was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved question #1

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    data:flowVars.infodata replace /(\[|\])/ with ""
}
```

I'm still trying to understand how to dynamically change the content of the payload for question #2.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looking at the sample flowVar content, it looks like an array of json object. Is that correct? If it is array then inside dataweave, you can either iterate over `flowVars.infodata map {}` or just get the first object `data: flowVars.infodata[0]`.
2. Not sure what you really mean by dynamically changing content. @star has shown a way how you can reference any variables inside your dataweave code. May be you can add some of your code that you are looking to edit?